# Bootstrap 2.2.1 Typeahead

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap

PHP, returns a JSON encoded array

```
$this->load->model('car_model', 'cars');
$result = $this->cars->searchBrand($this->input->post('query'));
$this->output->set_status_header(200);
$this->output->set_header('Content-type: application/json');
$output = array();
foreach($result as $r)
    $output['options'][$r->brandID] = $r->brandName;
print json_encode($output);
```

Outputs: `{"options":{"9":"Audi","10":"Austin","11":"Austin Healey"}}`

JS updated:

```
$(".searchcarBrands").typeahead({
    source: function(query, typeahead) {
        $.ajax({
            url: site_url + '/cars/search_brand/'+query,
            success: function(data) {
                typeahead.process(data);
            },
            dataType: "json"
        });
    },
    onselect: function(item) {
        $("#someID").val(item.id);
    }
});
```

UPDATE: Uncaught TypeError: Object function (){return a.apply(c,e.concat(k.call(arguments)))} has no method 'process'

If I type just 'A' then typeahead shows me only the first letter of each result (a bunch of A letters). If I type a second letter I see nothing anymore.

I've tried `JSON.parse` on the data or using data.options but no luck.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Are you essentially attempting to convert typeahead to allow a remote data source?

Comment: OK, see my answer - I believe my code should help you.

Answer (score 3):

I've been battling this for the last day with Bootstrap 2.2.1.  No matter what I did, it would not work.  For me, I always got the process undefined error unless I put a breakpoint in the process function (maybe just because FireBug was open?).

Anyway, as a patch I re-downloaded Bootstrap with typeahead omitted, got the typeahead from here:
https://gist.github.com/2712048

And used this code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('input[name=artist]').typeahead({
        'source': function (typeahead) {
            return $.get('/7d/search-artist.php', { 'artist': typeahead.query }, function (data) {
                return typeahead.process(data);
            });
        },
        'items': 3,
        'minLength': 3
    },'json')
});
```

My server returns this (for 'Bo'):

```
["Bo","Bo Burnham","Bo Diddley","Bo Bruce","Bo Carter",
 "Eddie Bo","Bo Bice","Bo Kaspers Orkester","Bo Saris","Bo Ningen"]
```

Of course, now it ignores my minLength, but it will get me through the day.  Hope this helps.

EDIT: Found the solution here:
[Bootstrap 2.2 Typeahead Issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13636088/bootstrap-2-2-typeahead-issue)

Using the typeahead included with Bootstrap 2.2.1, the code should read:

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('input[name=artist]').typeahead({
            'source': function (query,typeahead) {
                return $.get('/search-artist.php', { 'artist': encodeURIComponent(query) }, function (data) {
                    return typeahead(data);
                });
            },
            'items': 3,
            'minLength': 3
        },'json')
    });
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's what I do to facilitate remote data sources with bootstrap's typeahead:

```
$("#search").typeahead({

    source: function(typeahead, query) {

        $.ajax({

            url: "<?php echo base_url();?>customers/search/"+query,
            success: function(data) {

                typeahead.process(data);
            },
            dataType: "json"
        });
    },
    onselect: function(item) {

        $("#someID").val(item.id);
    }
});
```

And then you just need to make sure your JSON-encoded arrays contain a `value` index for the label and an `id` field to set your hidden id afterwards, so like:

```
$this->load->model('car_model', 'cars');
$brands = $this->cars->searchBrand($this->uri->segment(4));
$output = array();
foreach($brands->result() as $r) {

    $item['value'] = $r->brandName;
    $item['id']    = $r->brandID;
    $output[] = $item;
}
echo json_encode($output);
exit;
```

Comment: This gives me "Object a has no method 'process'" referring to typeahead.process

Comment: Shouldn't it say `Object typeahead has no method 'process'`?  Not, `object a`?  Can you post your updated code in your original post?

Comment: I follow you but no that's what it says 'a' is what I typed in the text field. Updated my original post.

Comment: Please update your server-side code, as you are not outputting proper JSON - see the second half my example (which is based on CodeIgniter).  Additionally, you are not passing the query through to your controller which means there will not be any filtering done.

Comment: I also got same error `TypeError: typeahead.process is not a function`. My controller return this json `[{"value":"UI Design","id":"1"},{"value":"Web technology","id":"2"}]`

Comment: Which version of typeahead are you using?  It's basically telling you the .js file that contains your typeahead object doesn't define a method "process"... which is strange.

Answer (score 0):

$.post is asynchronous, so you can't user return in it. That doesn't return anything.