# Bootstrap 2.2 Typeahead Issue

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I am using the following code to get suggestion list when I type on my text box.

`JS`

```
$("#address").typeahead({
    source: function(query,typeahead){ 
        $.ajax({
            url: "http://localhost/disc/autocomplete/"+query,
            type: "GET",
            dataType: "JSON",
            async: true,
            success: function(data){
                typeahead.process(data); 
            }
        });
    },
    property: 'address',
    items:8,
    onselect: function (obj) { 
        // window.location = obj.url;
    }   
});
```

`PHP`

```
    $count=0;
    foreach ($query->result() as $row)
    {
        $count++;
        $item['value'] = $row->address;
        $item['id'] = $count;
        $output[] = $item;
    }        
    echo json_encode($output);
```

`TextBox`

```
<input type="text" id="address" autocomplete="off" name="address" class="input-block-level" placeholder="Street address..">
```

Now when I type on the text box I am getting the error

```
Uncaught TypeError: Object function (){return a.apply(c,e.concat(k.call(arguments)))} has no method 'process'
```

EDIT:

```
$("#typeahead").typeahead({
    source: function(query,callback){ 
        $.ajax({
            url: "http://192.168.8.132/disc/autocomplete/"+query,
            type: "POST",
            dataType: "JSON",
            async: false,
            success: function(data){                   
                //this.process(data);
                callback(data);
            }
        });
    },
    items:8,
    onselect: function (obj) { 
    // window.location = obj.url;
    }   
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

what is typeahead ? you obviously needs to do something with it before invoking the process member. ( instanciation  , whatever typeahead is supposed to be ).

EDIT 1 :

```
source: function(query,callback/** you need that to execute something after the XMLHttp request has returned**/){ 
        $.ajax({
            url: "http://localhost/disc/autocomplete/"+query,
            type: "GET",
            dataType: "JSON",
            async: true,
            success: function(data){
                /** execute the callback here do whatever data processing you want before**/
                callback(data); 
            }
        });
    },
```

in functional programming it is called continuation ( like a GOTO instruction ).

EDIT 2 :

you do not decide what callback is , callback is function so dont try to do anything else than calling it with the data you received. Again , **callback** is a GOTO like instruction , it is a continuation , you dont control it. you need to execute it with data as parameter.

Comment: If you know what I mean, `typeahead` is a feature of `Bootstrap`. Do i have to instantiate tat ? If yes how do I do that ?

Comment: i know what Twitter bootstrap is , and what is type ahead , i'm talking about the source callback and the typeahead object your are passing to the source function. What is it ?

Comment: obviously i didn't understood that part then. I am not passing anything into the callback. can you please tel me what to do there ? actually my code looks just like as it is now. I am not hiding anything..

Comment: so i need to call `typehead.process(data)` shall i put that line inside callback function ?

Comment: no you dont need to call typehead.process(data) , you need to call the callback defined as an argument in the source function. if you want to do some data processing before that do it in the ajax callback or where ever you want but call the function variable directy as it is defined in the source function signature , just look at my code , it is not hard to understand what i'm doing. callback is a function.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/20357/discussion-between-deepak-and-camus)

Comment: Hi , sorry i dont have time for that, just take my snippet and paste it in your code. I dont understand what is the problem , since variables get injected in the source function by the typeahead , you dont control the variables passed and callback ( the 2d argument) is a function. read about Continuation.